# react-bootstrap: How can I make the Accordion work on React?

Tags: react-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I'm trying to use the Accordion component from `react-bootstrap` but I'm getting the following errors:

```
Line 22:18:  'Accordion' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 23:22:  'Card' is not defined       react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 24:26:  'Card' is not defined       react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 25:26:  'Accordion' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 25:47:  'Button' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 29:26:  'Accordion' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 30:26:  'Card' is not defined       react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 33:22:  'Card' is not defined       react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 34:26:  'Card' is not defined       react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 35:26:  'Accordion' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 35:47:  'Button' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 39:26:  'Accordion' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 40:26:  'Card' is not defined       react/jsx-no-undef
```

Any suggestions or guides of how to make it work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please post your code and what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have fixed grammar in the question and formatted the error output - both for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

if you have installed react bootstrap from npm and made the configurations that react bootstrap gives you. when you use react bootstrap component into some component or view you have to import theirs elements, in this case:

```
import {Accordion, Card, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

then you should use the component. i hope this work for you

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @MannyR you should accept the answer instead of saying thanks in the comments.